# ASP.NET 3 level of nested repeater

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to do 3 level of nested repeater from tables of a database. I have a Category that hold Groups of questions and groups of questions hold questions.

Would love to have a little example on how i can realize this scenario.

2 level of repeater is not that hard but when it come to 3 level that another story...

Note: I am using ASP.NET Webforms. Please, i don't want an example with DataSet or DataTable.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is 2 levels easy but 3 levels hard?

Comment: Because i haven't figured out yet how to make one lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to do nesting of repeating controls manually to eliminate DB calls.

Do 3 DB calls to get all your level data. First call get your master data.  Second call get all the possible data for all the master records.  Third call get all the child data possible from the second calls results.

Then store that all in a globally accessible variable.  Implement the `OnDataBinding` of each nested repeater.  For each `OnDataBinding` event pull off the 'key' and perform a filter on the nested data and bind it.

Eg:

```
DataSet1 - Master data
DataSet2 - All possible child data for DataSet1
DataSet3 - All possible child data for DataSet2

Repeater1 - Bind to DataSet1
Repeater2 - OnDataBinding bind the filtered DataSet2 based on DataSet1 current key
Repeater3 - OnDataBinding bind the filtered DataSet3 based on DataSet2 current key
```

Comment: I would point out that it's cleaner and more performant to get multiple resultsets (tables) in a single dataset. At least if you're using SQL Server that works well enough. You can then bind the repeaters to the individual tables.

Comment: @kprobst yes I agree. I would do it all in one call with mutliple result sets.  I was trying to break it into simple steps :)  When I say `DataSet` I don't actually mean a real `DataSet` but instead a 'set of data'. It could be anything like `List<>` etc or a `DataSet` with mutliple `Tables`.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Kelsey's answer (which I would vote up if I had enough rep here, but this is my very first post on StackExchange - but I will when I'm able! EDIT: I've up-voted it!), here's some code that may help, since I had to do this exact thing (with using different types of groups, but essentially it's the same), and Kelsey's answer helped me too.

Note that this is probably not perfect, but it does work for me. I'm interested in improving it. It is ever-so-slightly different than Kelsey's approach.

In my case, I am using 3 levels of nested repeaters in a navigation menu in an ASP.NET (VB) application.

First, set up a dataset to bind to the parent repeater in your code-behind. (I know you said you aren't interested in answers with datasets or datatables, but I'm not sure of a better way - SOMETHING must be databound to the repeaters...)

```
' first load up some datatables with some data.
' you will probably want to optimize how you are grabbing the data
Dim dtCategories As DataTable = GetCategories
Dim dtQuestionGroups As DataTable = GetQuestionGroups
Dim dtQuestions As DataTable = GetQuestions

' name the tables
dtCategories.TableName = "Categories"
dtQuestionGroups.TableName = "QuestionGroups"
dtQuestions.TableName = "Questions"

' add the datatables to a dataset and set some relationships
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
ds.Tables.Add(dtCategories)
ds.Tables.Add(dtQuestionGroups)
ds.Tables.Add(dtQuestions)

' note that your column name identifiers may be different.
ds.Relations.Add("CatQgrp", _ 
    ds.Tables("Categories").Columns("id"), _ 
    ds.Tables("QuestionGroups").Columns("CatID"))

ds.Relations.Add("QgrpQues", _ 
    ds.Tables("QuestionGroups").Columns("id"), _ 
    ds.Tables("Questions").Columns("QgrpID"))

' bind to repeater. only need to bind the parent table
parentRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables("Categories")
parentRepeater.DataBind()
```

So now that we have the data set up, we can display it on the aspx page.

```
<ul>
    <li>CATEGORIES
        <ul>
            <asp:repeater id="parentRepeater" runat="server">
                <itemtemplate>
                    <li><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CategoryName")%>
                        <ul>
                            <!-- start child repeater 1, which will show the question groups-->
                            <asp:repeater id="childRepeater1" datasource='<%# Container.DataItem.Row.GetChildRows("CatQgrp") %>' runat="server">
                                <itemtemplate>
                                    <li><%# Container.DataItem("QgrpName")%>
                                        <ul>
                                            <!-- start child repeater 2, which will show the questions-->
                                            <asp:repeater id="childRepeater2" datasource='<%# Container.DataItem.GetChildRows("QgrpQues") %>' runat="server">
                                                <itemtemplate>
                                                    <li><%# Container.DataItem("QuestionName")%></li>
                                                </itemtemplate>
                                            </asp:repeater>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </itemtemplate>
                            </asp:repeater>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </itemtemplate>
            </asp:repeater>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

YMMV, and you'll need to change the column names to whatever you are using in your database tables of course, but this should get you started.