# 3 nested repeaters with Sql tables

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have three tables as follows: table 1 is called Cat1, table 2 is called subcat1 and table three is called itemsTb. I have created relationships like this:

cat1 to subcat1 (one-to-many)
cat1 to itemstb (one-to-many)
subcat1 to itemstb (one-to-many)

I would like to display items in asp.net repeaters like this:

```
cat 1....
   ....item 1
   ....item 2
   ....item 3
cat 2
   subcat 1 .....
      .....item 1
      .....item 2
      .....item 3
cat 3.....
   ....item 1
   ....item 2

etc.

The schema of my tables is like this:

Table: cat
columns:
id      int
title   varchar

table  subcat
columns:
id     int
catid  int
title  varchar

table: items
columns
id         int
catid      int
subcatid   int
title      varchar
```

Anyone has any idea how can I display them using asp.net repeaters? Or do I have to structure my tables differently to make it work? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Previously asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454129/efficient-way-binding-nested-repeater-3-levels-deep.  I should have looked before answering.  Sorry, voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: There's working code at this answer as well:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159736/asp-net-3-level-of-nested-repeater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the ASP.NET databound controls (Repeater, ListView, GridView, etc.) can use declarative data-binding for their DataSource. This isn't very well documented IMO, but you can do something like:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCategory">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptSubcategory" DataSource='<%#Eval("Subcategories")%>'>
             <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptItems" DataSource='<%#Eval("Items")%>'>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#Eval("Name")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The specifics of what you need to bind to the `DataSource` property depends on what your initial data (the one that rptCategory is bound to).

If it's a `DataSet`, then you need to build `DataRelations` and use the name of the appropriate `DataRelation`.

If it's a C# object, then you'll want to use the name of a collection property.

EDIT: Specifics on this particular schema follow....

For your schema, you would need 2 nested repeaters - 1 to handle the items and 1 to handle the subcategories (which would have another nested repeater for its items).

Using DataSets, you could do something like (note this is rough code, you'll need to fill in some of the missing steps):

```
var ds = ExecuteDataSet(
   @"SELECT Id, Title FROM Cat;
   SELECT Id, CatId, Title FROM SubCat;
   SELECT Id, CatId, SubCatId, Title FROM Items;"
);
ds.DataRelations.Add("Cat_SubCat", ds.Tables["Cat"].Columns["Id"], ds.Tables["SubCat"].Columns["CatId"]);
ds.DataRelations.Add("Cat_Items", ds.Tables["Cat"].Columns["Id"], ds.Tables["Items"].Columns["CatId"]);
ds.DataRelations.Add("SubCat_Items", ds.Tables["SubCat"].Columns["Id"], ds.Tables["Items"].Columns["SubCatId"]);

this.rptCategory.DataSource = ds;
this.rptCategory.DataBind();

<asp:Repeater ID="rptCategory">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h2>Category <%#Eval("Title")%></h2>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptCatItems" DataSource='<%#Eval("Cat_Items")%>'>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <h4>Item (Category) <%#Eval("Title")%></h4>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptCatSubCat" DataSource='<%#Eval("Cat_SubCat")%>'>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <h3>SubCategory <%#Eval("Title")%></h3>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptSubCatItems" DataSource='<%#Eval("SubCat_Items")%>'>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <h4>Item (SubCategory) <%#Eval("Title")%></h4>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Mark, I have items that need to be shown immediately under rptCategory and then there are items that are shown under rptSubCat.

How do I write the logic to get this?

Comment: @IH-77 - you'll need to provide details of your queries and/or schemas. Basically, you *don't* want to treat them the same - so you need someway to split them out. A lot depends on how you're getting the data in the first place (SqlDataSource? Custom objects? EF?)

Comment: I have used the same thing as described in the article that David mentioned above: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306154.

for the schema of my tables please look in my first question above.

Comment: @IH-77 - You need multiple repeaters in the top-group. Pseudo-code sample added.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. I will give it a try and let you know about my the result.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft provides guidance on this.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306154

(Sorry this isn't longer but this is fairly straight-forward and covered well in hte article.)

Comment: Thanks a lot David for your quick reply. I have seen that article but I still don't know how to solve the above problem that I have. This article shows only two level of hierarchy of data.

Comment: Adding the third level is exactly the same as adding the second.  Define the relationships and the aspx syntax for the third level is the same as it is for the second.

Comment: There's working code at this answer as well:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159736/asp-net-3-level-of-nested-repeater

Comment: I would like something like this
cat 1
  items
  items
cat 2
  subcat 1
     items
     items
  sub cat 2
     items
cat 3
  items
  items